# Is it possible to subclass the immutable date class and override the __str__ method?

Tags: python, datetime, date, subclass, immutability

I am trying to subclass the immutable `date` class in Python, but I also need to override the `__str__` method. So far, I have the following:

```
from datetime import date

class Year(date):
    def __new__(cls, year):
        return super(Year, cls).__new__(cls, year, 1, 1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.strftime('%Y')
```

Constructor works fine, but the `__str__` method is completely ignored when I try to print the object. I have seen a few samples subclassing other immutable classes such as `int` and `float`. All of them were using the same convention. Am I missing something? Is there anything special for the `date` object?

UPDATE:

It seems that there is nothing wrong with the code. I was trying to print a `Year` object inside a Django template and since Django formats `date` objects using a localizable format `__str__` method was being ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `return` to the `__str__` method.

---

**UPDATE:**

I ran your *updated* code on my machine, and it works fine:

```
aj@localhost:~/so/python# cat date2.py
from datetime import date

class Year(date):
    def __new__(cls, year):
        return super(Year, cls).__new__(cls, year, 1, 1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.strftime('%Y')

y=Year(2011)
print str(y)
aj@localhost:~/so/python# python date2.py
2011
```

Comment: Well, that is just a copy/paste error. I have edited the code.

Comment: You are right, it is working. I was printing the value using Django templates. Apparently, it is ignoring the `__str__` method.

Comment: You could always force it using `str(o)`

Answer (score 1):

If this is your complete code you are missing the return statement:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.strftime('%Y')
```

Comment: Well, that is just a copy/paste error. I have edited the code.